# when using "pgrep" in shell script, showing 2 pids including real process's pid.(terminal output only shows 1 pid - real process's pid.)

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I use CentOS 7.7 on my linux server.

below is my terminal output :

```
# pgrep -f 'process_name'
19737
```

after checking the output, I made shell script like below :

```
#!/bin/sh
test_pid=$(pgrep -f 'process_name')
echo ${test_pid}
```

but when running shell scripts, I got output like below(2 pids) :

```
19737, 10324
```

I tried same thing with the cmd like "ps -ef |grep -v grep |grep 'process_name' | awk {pring $2}" as well.

when I tested it in terminal, I got 1 pid(19737).
but when I run it in the shell script, I got "19737, 1067, 1068" - (3 pids).

I don't know how they work...

is there someone who knows the reason and how to get only 1 real process pid?

thank you.

=============================================================

hello. I resolved the issue with using 2 options like below :

```
pgrep -U 'process_uid' -f 'process_name'
```

In my case, it works.
thank you.

Comment: Why are you using `-f`?

Comment: hello. cause I have multiple processes in my server with same uid, gid. so I try to find pid with the specific keyword('process_name') on the process command line.